# Angular library for flowchart builder or workflow editor

Tags: angular, workflow, flowchart

I am currently looking for an open-source library for flowchart builder or workflow editor for frontend webapp in angular.

I have looked at [jsplumb](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demos.html) and [jointjs](https://www.jointjs.com/). But the angular wrapper for both these libraries are licensed.

I have also checked [mxgraph](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph). But there is no angular wrapper available for it.

Please let me know if someone has implemented flowchart builder or workflow editor in angular using open-source libraries.

Comment: jsplumb has a free version with some good options, i forked it and used and developed it was OK and easy to work.

Comment: you had to write angular wrapper around jsplumb to use with your application or you could directly integrate it with angular?

Comment: you can directly work with it check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsplumb

Comment: this is a very simple example which does not explore the complexities with developing a flow chart builder/editor. looks like it would take a lot of effort to go with this approach. was looking for something which would be readily available as a flow chart editor component

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the NGX-Graph - graph visualization library for Angular: https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-graph/

Comment: Check also Sequential Workflow Designer for Angular: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequential-workflow-designer-angular